# How to write XSL tags for dynamic XML nodes

Tags: xslt

This is my XML:

```
<AUDITDATA>
  <USERS>
    <Domain>DOMAUDIT</Domain>
    <UserName>Aashu</UserName>
    <PassWord>m0eYN2VM</PassWord>
    <Description>1234</Description>
    <UserType>AdminOps</UserType>
    <UserRoles.Painter>YES</UserRoles.Painter>
    <UserRoles.Driver>NO</UserRoles.Driver>
    <UserRoles.Cook>YES</UserRoles.Cook>
    <!-- like this there may be more roles also.-->
  </USERS>
</AUDITDATA>
```

For XML Tags apart from "UserRoles.*" I have wriiten XSL code lyke this:

```
<xsl:template name="Users">

  <xsl:call-template name="FormatTextData">
    <xsl:with-param name="textValue" select="//UserName"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="displayValue" select="'User Name='"/>
  </xsl:call-template>

 <xsl:call-template name="FormatTextData">
    <xsl:with-param name="textValue" select="//PassWord"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="displayValue" select="',Password='"/>
  </xsl:call-template>

 <xsl:call-template name="FormatTextData">
    <xsl:with-param name="textValue" select="//Description"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="displayValue" select="',Description='"/>
  </xsl:call-template>

 <xsl:call-template name="FormatTextData">
    <xsl:with-param name="textValue" select="//UserType"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="displayValue" select="',User Type='"/>
  </xsl:call-template>    

</xsl:template>
```

And this is working fine for others tags, how to write for UserRoles tags, as you can see the no of Roles are not fixed, I want to tackel all roles via one block of code in XSL file.

The Problem is, how to define a XSL for XML tags, whose TagName is not static, or only a part is static.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I don't really follow your XSL, but you can select all the UserRoles.* elements by:

```
select="AUDITDATA/USERS/*[starts-with(name(), 'UserRoles.')]"
```